# With verbs like ricordarsi is the "di" still required before noun clauses used as direct objects as in the example below?

Tags: grammar

I wrote you once before because I love your website and the Podcasts.  Perhaps you could help me one more time.

Duo gives the sentence:

I remember when I saw the queen.

I answered:

Ricordo quando ho visto la regina.

It was considered correct but mentioned that another possibility was:

Mi ricordo quando ho visto la regina.

I had chosen ricordare rather than ricordarsi because "when I saw the queen"  seemed to be a noun clause functioning as a direct object (What did I remember?  I remembered "when I saw the queen") and ricordare is a transitive verb requiring nothing before the direct object but "di" before a verb (i.e. Ricordo di fare i compiti).

However, I know that ricordarsi, though intransitive, is frequently used in speech but requires "di" before a direct object or a verb.

Someone raised the question as to whether it should have been:

Mi ricordo di quando ho visto la regina

but his name was not Italian and he did not say he was a native speaker.  I had considered "Mi recordo quando ho visto la regina" but went with ricordare as discussed above and because it avoided the problem with "di."  I couldn't remember seeing di in front of a noun clause, only in front of a direct object noun, but that could be my limited experience.

The problem with the prepositions comes up multiple times a week in the Duo sessions and unfortunately there are many more uncorrected errors in the Italian section than the Spanish or French sections.  Looking over my notes there is a lack of consistency.  When a verb requires "di" or "a" or occasionally other prepositions before a direct object, if the direct object is replaced by a noun clause is the preposition still required?  Perhaps a native speaker, teacher, or someone who speaks Italian more fluently than me might comment.

Comment: In my personal opinion "Mi ricordo di quando ho visto la regina" has a slightly more indirect nuance that "Mi ricordo quando ho visto la regina"; it's like you want to say that you remember _the circumstances in which you saw the queen_ In english I would maybe translate it like "I remember about when I saw the queen"

Comment: _Ricordarsi_ is not necessarily intransitive: see https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/ricordarsi, which gives, among other examples, _mi ricordo bene quella vacanza in Grecia_. This should indirectly solve at least part of your doubts.

Comment: This said, I'm not sure that whatever holds for _ricordare_ / _ricordarsi_ automatically applies to other verbs.

Comment: I agree with Riccardo. IMHO "Mi ricordo di quando ho visto la regina" has some kind of subjective connotation to it, while "Ricordo quando ho visto la regina" is purely objective. I would translate it in English with something like "I recall the time I saw the queen" (I am a native speaker).

Comment: @jackdbd: In your examples the strongest difference is given by _mi ricordo_ vs _ricordo_, rather than by the presence or absence of _di_, which is the subject of the question.